# Is it possible to select a window in Ubuntu via script? If so how?

Tags: shell-script, window-manager

I'd like to possibly select a window via a script.  That is perhaps after running some shell script I'd like to bring to the foreground a window, a browser, another terminal, etc.  Is this possible?  How could I do this?

`/etc/X11/default-display-manager` says I'm using `/usr/bin/gdm3` (gnome dislay manager)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Use `xdotool` to do it.

1. Get the window id by doing `xdotool search window` where window is the window you want to focus. Remember the output.
2. Run `xdotool selectwindow id` where id is the output of the previous command.